# Adding all indexes of arrays to one single array

Tags: java

I was wondering if this is the most efficient or even good code practice to add arrays to a single array as far as my knowllage goes its time would be `O(n)`. This is only for practice and I want to do it for `int []` not for the code to be changed so it is a `List`.

```
static int[] allArrayDirections(int row[], int col [], int diag []) {
    int counter = 0;
    int allDirectionsInMatrix [] = new int [row.length  + col.length + diag.length];
    
    for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        allDirectionsInMatrix[counter++] = row[i];
        
    }
    
    for(int j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        allDirectionsInMatrix[counter++] = col[j];
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < diag.length; i++) {
        allDirectionsInMatrix[counter++] = diag[i];
    }
    
    
    return allDirectionsInMatrix;
}
```

Comment: [java.lang.System#arrayCopy()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare your linear solution to a sort of unravelled:

1. Find the longest of the three arrays, take its length as counter boundary
2. assign the longest array to a new variable first, the other two to second and third – just fiddling with the references so the for looks straightforward
3. loop once from 0 to the counter boundary
4. fill your target array in three steps, using the other array's length as offset – unless the smaller arrays are already exhausted, so skip them

This will need some add operation for the offset calculation to write to allDirectionsInMatrix and two greater then checks. Depending on the VM's optimization/ array lengths/ call frequency this might cut it in half.

The single for-loop looks similar to this:

```
// assuming first.length >= second.length >= third.length;
for(int i=0;i<largestLength;i++) {
  allDirectionsInMatrix[i]=first[i];
  
  if (second.length > i) 
    allDirectionsInMatrix[i+first.length]=second[i];

  // I assume when called often enough VM does auto trickery
  // with the repeated addition of i and first.length
  if (third.length > i)
    allDirectionsInMatrix[i+first.length+second.length]=third[i];
}
```

But this might also break other VM optimizations when treating the arrays independently. So really compare runtime. I'd appreciate to read about your measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI (and not a reals answer to your question, but maybe interesting for comparison)

One way to concatenate integer arrays (using Streams) would be

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
int[] b = {4,5,6,7};

int[] c = IntStream.concat(Arrays.stream(a), Arrays.stream(b)).toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(c));
```

(Stream.concat for arrays of other types)